# Matlab: trigonometric form of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series, matlab

I have tried to implement a matlab function that computes a Fourier series of a discrete periodic signal using its trigonometric form. The Fourier series can be obtained with:

\begin{align}
s_{\scriptscriptstyle N}(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N \left(a_n \cos\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{T} nx \right) + b_n \sin\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{T} nx \right) \right).
\end{align}


\begin{align}
a_0 &= \frac{1}{T}\int_{T} f(x) dx\\
b_0 &= 0\\
\end{align}

for   $n>0$:

\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{2}{T}\int_{T} f(x)\cdot  \cos\left( \tfrac{2\pi}{T} nx \right)\, dx\\
b_n &= \frac{2}{T}\int_{T} f(x)\cdot  \sin\left( \tfrac{2\pi}{T} nx \right)\, dx
\end{align}

I have therefor implemented the following Matlab function:

```
function fFS = get_fourier_trigo(f, T, t, dt, N, k_plot)
    figure()
    plot(t, f,'-k', 'LineWidth',1.5, 'DisplayName', 'Original')
    hold on

    % Compute Fourier series
    A0 = (1/T)*sum(f)*dt % This corresponds to the mean value
    fFS = A0/2;
    for n=1:N
        A(n) = (2/T)*sum(f.*cos(n*t*2*pi/T))*dt;
        B(n) = (2/T)*sum(f.*sin(n*t*2*pi/T))*dt;
        fFS = fFS + A(n)*cos(n*t*2*pi/T) + B(n)*sin(n*t*2*pi/T);
        if mod(n, k_plot) == 0 
            plot(t, fFS, '-', 'LineWidth', 0.5, 'DisplayName', int2str(n))
        end
    end
    title('Fourier Series')
    legend show
end
```

But unfortunately my reconstructed Fourier series does not match my original signal:

```
dt = 1/100;
T = 1; % signal period
t = (-1+dt:dt:1)*T/2;
f = 2*sin(2*pi*t) + 0.5*sin(2*pi*5*t)
N = 5;
y_s = get_fourier_trigo(f, T, t, dt, N, 1);
```

[Results of Fourier series approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTON1.png)

I found out that if I modify my function by removing the $\frac{1}{T}, \frac{2}{T}$ for the estimation of $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively then my obtained Fourier series converges to my original signal:

```
dt = 1/100;
T = 1; % signal period
t = (-1+dt:dt:1)*T/2;
f = 2*sin(2*pi*t) + 0.5*sin(2*pi*5*t)
N = 5;
y_s = get_fourier_trigo_corrected(f, T, t, dt, N, 1);

function fFS = get_fourier_trigo_corrected(f, T, t, dt, N, k_plot)
    figure()
    plot(t, f,'-k', 'LineWidth',1.5, 'DisplayName', 'Original')
    hold on

    % Compute Fourier series
    A0 = sum(f)*dt % This corresponds to the mean value
    fFS = A0/2;
    for n=1:N
        A(n) = sum(f.*cos(n*t*2*pi/T))*dt;
        B(n) = sum(f.*sin(n*t*2*pi/T))*dt;
        fFS = fFS + A(n)*cos(n*t*2*pi/T) + B(n)*sin(n*t*2*pi/T);
        if mod(n, k_plot) == 0 
            plot(t, fFS, '-', 'LineWidth', 0.5, 'DisplayName', int2str(n))
        end
    end
    title('Fourier Series')
    legend show
end
```

[Results of the modified Fourier series approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DJOo.png)

Can anyone explain me where is my mistake / misunderstanding?

**Update:**
I have implemented the changes suggested by @jean marie and it works well for sum of sines waves but I now face an issue with obtaining the Fourier series of a pulse signal. I have also replaced the sums by a numerical integration using `trapz`:

```
dt = 1/1000; % sampling time
T = pi; % periodicity
t = (0:dt:1-dt)*T;

% split interval in quarters
n = length(t);   
nquart = floor(n/4);

% Pulse function
f = 0*t;  
f(nquart:3*nquart) = 1;

% Fourier approximation
N = 50;
kplot = 10;

fs = get_fourier_trigo(f, T, t, dt, N, kplot);
%% Functions
function fFS = get_fourier_trigo(f, T, t, dt, N, k_plot)
    figure()
    plot(t, f,'-k','LineWidth',1.5, 'DisplayName', 'Original')
    hold on

    % Compute Fourier series
    A0 = (1/T)*trapz(t,f) % This corresponds to the mean value
    fFS = A0/2;
    wt = t*2*pi/T;
    for n=1:N
        A(n) = (2/T)*trapz(t ,f.*cos(n*wt));
        B(n) = (2/T)*trapz(t, f.*sin(n*wt));
        fFS = fFS + A(n)*cos(n*wt) + B(n)*sin(n*wt);
        if mod(n, k_plot) == 0 
            plot(t, fFS, '-', 'LineWidth', 0.5, 'DisplayName', int2str(n))
        end
    end
    title('Fourier Series')
    legend show

end
```

[Fourier series for a pulse signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBpyy.png)

Comment: Have you attempted to take a much smaller step such as $dt=1/10000$ ?

Comment: Yes I did but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: $n$ is always an integer in the function:
$n$ successively takes the integer values from 1 to N but is never a list per se.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now: it is $t$ which is a list...

Comment: You are simply off by a constant factor. ($2$ ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I propose as a reference is to take

$$t=(0:dt:1)*T\tag{1}$$

But your approach with

$$t = (-1+dt:dt:1)*T/2;\tag{2}$$

is perfectly valid **under the condition that the "differential element" $dt$ (= $\Delta t$) is divided by 2** (see below the line with comments %%%%%%%%%).

Why that ? Because in case (2), one uses twice as many values of $f$ than in case (1), therefore it has to be compensated by taking a differential element divided by 2 !

Please note that factors $(2/T)$ are to be kept in front of formulas for $A(n)$ and $B(n)$.

> ```
> function m;
> clear all;close all;hold on;
> dt = 1/1000;
> T = 1; % signal period
> % Approach (1):
> % t = (0:dt:1)*T;
> % f=2*sin(2*pi*t)+0.5*cos(2*pi*5*t)+3*cos(2*pi*3*t);
> % plot(t,f,'c','linewidth',3);
> % "Your" approach (2)... perfectly valid:
> t=(-1+dt:dt:1)*T/2;
> dt=dt/2; % <- %%%%%%%%%%%%... under this condition 
> % (that will be applied later on)
> f =2*sin(2*pi*t)+0.5*cos(2*pi*5*t)+3*cos(2*pi*3*t);
> plot(t,f,'c','linewidth',3)
> plot(t,f,'c','linewidth',3)
> N = 5;
> get_fourier_trigo(f, T, t, dt, N, 1);
> %
> function get_fourier_trigo(f, T, t, dt, N, k_plot)
> s='rgbcmyrgbcmy';
> A0 = (2/T)*sum(f)*dt;
> fFS = A0/2;
> u=t*2*pi/T;
> for n=1:N
>    A(n) = (2/T)*sum(f.*cos(n*u))*dt
>    B(n) = (2/T)*sum(f.*sin(n*u))*dt
>    fFS = fFS + A(n)*cos(n*u) + B(n)*sin(n*u);
>    c=s(n); % plotting color
>    plot(t, fFS, '-','color',c, 'LineWidth', 0.5, 'DisplayName', int2str(n));
> end
> title('Fourier Series')
> legend show
> ```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you need to integrate on the interval $[0; T]$ and not $[-T/2; T/2]$ ? I thought I could integrate on any interval of length T...

Comment: Rectification: indeed, you are perfectly right when saying that we should obtain the same result using any interval of length $T$, be it $[0,T]$ or $[T/2,T/2]$ ; it has taken me some time before realizing that the issue is in the second case to take a "dt" divided by two because in this case we take twice as many values of $f$. **See my updated answer**.

Comment: Oh yes you are perfectly right, the problem was in the creation of the time vector. Thank you for spotting this out!

Comment: I could have said it otherwise by taking the same $dt$ but with $(-\frac12+dt:dt:\frac12)$.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have some issues. I now try to obtain the Fourier series of a pulse. `% Define function
dt = 1/1000; % sampling time
T = 1; % periodicity
t = (0:dt:1-dt)*T;

% split interval in quarters
n = length(t);   
nquart = floor(n/4);

% Pulse function
f = 0*t;  
f(nquart:3*nquart) = 1;`

I have alse replaced the sums by numerical integration using `trapz` but it does not help.

Comment: I will have a look at my program. You should find a convergence with a so-called "Gibbs phenomenon" (spikes at discontinuities).

Comment: Exactly... I have updated my question with the latest code and results.

Comment: The problem looks to be "translational", i.e., due to a bad $a_0$...

Comment: Changing the $a_0$ factor from $1/T$ to $2/T$  or simply not dividing $a_0$ by 2 solve the problem but does not help my understanding :)

Comment: Sorry, I was out for a whole day. The explanation is very simple : the usual formula for $A0$ is $A0 = (\color{red}{2}/T)*sum(f)*dt;$ and then after $fFS = A0/2;$ (we didn't pay attention to it before, neither you nor me because $A0$ was $0$ with the examples we had taken).

Comment: Besides, "trapz" is a better choice with improved precision compared to basic summing. Do you know that you can  use "integral" which is even better ?

Comment: I removed the accepted answer as the A0 coefficients was still wrong but now it's all good. I will try with integral if I can see an improvement.